# how to slice string from specific string in python

Tags: python

ok, so lets say I have

```
s = 'ABC Here DEF GHI toHere JKL'
```

and I want to get a new string with only the string between `Here` and `toHere`

```
new_str = 'DEF GHI'
```

(I dont know how many or which chars I have before `Here` or any where else)
I just know that I have `Here` and `toHere` in the string.
how can I get the `new_str`?

Comment: `import re;print(re.findall("Here(.*)toHere",target_string))` ... I guess

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is to use slicing:

```
s[s.find('Here') + len('Here') : s.find('toHere')]
#' DEF GHI '
```

You can `.strip()` off the white space from the result if you want.

Comment: thanks a lot! thats what I have been searching for

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful using index

```
str1 = 'ABC Here DEF GHI toHere JKL' 
try:
    start=str1.index('Here')+len('Here')
    end=str1.index('toHere')

    print(str1[start:end].strip())
except ValueError:
    print('Either of the substring not found')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate` and `.split()` to grab the proper indexes for your new slice, then `' '.join()` that new slice

```
s = 'ABC Here DEF GHI toHere JKL'
s = s.split()
for i, v in enumerate(s):
    if v == 'Here':
        start = i + 1
    if v == 'toHere':
        end = i
print(' '.join(s[start:end]))
# DEF GHI
```

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is to use splitting (imho)

```
print(s.split("Here",1)[-1].split("toHere",1)[0])
```

of coarse if `Here` is not present or `toHere` is not present it will not work how you expect (it will suffer the same consequences as the other solutions)